# _unicode_( ) function error in django

Tags: python, django, unicode, django-models

i am getting this problem,

```
class Poll(models.Poll):
    def _unicode_(self):
        return (self.question)
```

This should return object, but returns:

```
Poll: Poll Object
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Watch the [`Dunder`](https://wiki.python.org/moin/DunderAlias)!

The method should be called [`__unicode__()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/#unicode), not `_unicode_()`:

```
class Poll(models.Poll)
    def __unicode__(self)
        return(self.question)
```